# installation of odtone in ubuntu

Tags: boost

Please someone help me in the installation of odtone in ubuntu!
I'm new to ubuntu and know only few commands!
One PDF suggests to install boost libraries and compile them manually!
Please explain what is manual compilation. I'd be grateful if someone suggest me the commands for that compilation also.

Comment: This belongs on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation at http://atnog.av.it.pt/odtone/documentation.html, see the section "Getting Started". The PDF is outdated, the most current documentation is only available in HTML.